# Install Fusioninventory with .bat, with GPO Policy script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, active-directory, group-policy

I need help creating a GPO to run a .bat running an .exe with installation commands. I have the problem that the policy of the company prevents it from running an .exe without administrator permissions. Even if I apply the GPO successfully, the .exe is not executed and the installation I want is not done. the GPO replicates in other GPO servers and is for many desktop.

Update 23/4/2019

Option 1:
Run as disabled:(FAIL)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjjL3.png

Option 2:
Parameters script:(FAIL)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdYzY.png

Option 3:
Script Powershell, execute .bat with privileges: (FAIL, lack of experience in powershell)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIxYb.png

Option 4: ...Please HELP-ME...

Script:

```
\\MTAD300\Util\Finventory\fusioninventory-agent_windows-x64_2.4.2.exe /debug=1 /acceptlicense /server='https://ayuda.servidor.com/plugins/fusioninventory' /delaytime=60 /execmode=service /add-firewall-exception /installtasks=full /runnow /S
```

Comment: you could create a scheduled task in your GPO to deploy to your clients, that is set to run as a different user (domainadmin) which runs your .exe once https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a42850b1-850b-404c-9a4b-775589180f15/create-and-run-scheduled-task-thru-gpo-using-nonadmin-users?forum=winserverGP

Comment: run as, is disabled in the GPO task properties, is there a way that the .bat, that the user and password are automatically filled in silent mode ?, or that inside the .bat or Powershell is the user and pass to run the program with its installation configuration declared in .bat.

Comment: Yes, in PowerShell you can do this. you just need to create a credential object https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/koteshb/2010/02/12/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object/ and wrap your command like so `Invoke-Command { <your command> } -Credential $mycreds`

Comment: $user = Read-Host ".\adm_soporte"

$passwd = Read-Host "A17a5#2018" -AsSecureString

$passwd = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($passwd))

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "$passwd" -AsPlainText -Force

$creden = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$user", $secpasswd)

$session= -Credential $creden

Invoke-Command $session {"\\MTNWAD300\SysVol\ayuda.servidor.com\Policies\{52CB9E5A-CEC7-4C43-93C2-6AED1CBF6412}\Machine\Scripts\Startup\ParametrosFusion.bat"}

Comment: So were my powershell lines, the .bat that runs is the one above, do you think it's enough to make it work ?, thanks for your advice. I will try and tell you.Thanks